# Do a visual select on search in Vim

Tags: search, vim, highlight

What is a simple way to do a visual select on the item I searched for in Vim?

I would like to map my <kbd>n</kbd> key to not only go to the next search item but also select it. Similarly for <kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd>.

Looking this up gave me answers to *searching for selected items*, but I want to *select searched items*.

Comment: Are you trying to only select the search term and not the area in between the search terms?  Are you maybe trying to do this just to get a better view of where the search terms are?  If that's the case, take a look at `:help hlsearch`.

Comment: Visual selections cannot have non-selected portions in between them. Thus if you'd like to do something with multiple terms other commands like `:g` or `:%s` are more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
nnoremap ,n //b<CR>v//e<CR>
vnoremap ,n <Esc>//b<CR>//e<CR>n
```

. This does not work for one-character matches. For `*` it will look like this:

```
nnoremap ,* *v//e<CR>
```

. None of the solutions work with one character matches, you may try adding `h` before `//e`, but this won’t work at the start of the line. I would not suggest to remap default keys due to the mentioned problems.

Answer (score 1):

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_or_change_search_hit

Comment: It seems mapping is so simple that some folks on vim-use used exactly the same code for them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post an answer that consists of just a link to an external site. Put real content directly in your post; include the link as a reference for further information. See [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).